# AngularJS - Redirect to Login page and Persistence of Session ID

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for a way to do these two things, first I want to redirect the user to a login page if no SessionID is found and second I would like to hear your opinion about persisting session ID in memory only (no cookies).

The solution I came up with for the redirect is:

1 - Create a service called OAuth that will check if SessionID exists and if not, redirects to login page, the service is also responsible for the login and logout methods.

```
app.factory('OAuth', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var _SessionID = '';

    return { 
        login: function () {
            //Do login ans store sessionID in var _SessionID
        },

        logout: function () {
            //Do logout
        },

        isLoggedIn: function () {
            if(_SessionID) {
                return true;
            }
            //redirect to login page if false
        }
    };

}]);
```

2 - Inject the new OAuth service in each controller and check if user isLoggedIn

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'OAuth', function ($scope, OAuth) {

    //check if user is logged
    OAuth.isLoggedIn();

}]);
```

Questions:

1 - The isLoggedIn() method will be called in all controllers, so I wonder if there is a way to do this without having to inject the service and call it in each controller.

2 - Instead of having a cookie to store the sessionID I want to save it in OAuth's _SessionID variable and for each request send it to the server. Is this a viable/secure approach? Can you give me some ideas for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would start [here](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth), Witold has created this cool interceptor that works off of http responses. I use it and its been really helpful.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the tip Dan!

Comment: The [writeup about the approach](http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application) is very helpful as well.

Answer (score 9):

I use a similar strategy (intercepting 401 responses from the server).  You can check out the full example here : https://github.com/Khelldar/Angular-Express-Train-Seed

It uses node and mobgodb on the backend for session store and a trimmed down http interceptor on the client that doens't retry requests like the one Dan linked above:

```
 var interceptor = ['$q', '$location', '$rootScope', function ($q, $location, $rootScope) {
        function success(response) {
            return response;
        }

        function error(response) {
            var status = response.status;
            if (status == 401) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }

        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(success, error);
        }
    }];
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used

1. interceptor with $httpProvider
2. config
3. and $window dependency, as $location just appended the path to the existing url. What happened was like "http://www.tnote.me/#/api/auth", and it should have bene like "http://www.tnote.me/auth"

The code snippet is like this.

```
noteApp = angular.module('noteApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
  .factory('authInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$cookies', '$window', 
    function($rootScope, $q, $cookies, $window) {
      return {
        request: function (req) {
          req.headers = req.headers || {};
          if ($cookies.token) {
            req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookies.token;  
          }

          return req;
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
          if (rejection.status == 401) {
            $window.location = '/auth';      
          }

          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      }
  }])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');  
    }
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

> this will work. It works fine in my application

```
var interceptor = function ($q, $location) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {//req
                console.log(config);
                return config;
            },

            response: function (result) {//res
                console.log('Repos:');
                console.log(result.status);
                return result;
            },

            responseError: function (rejection) {//error
                console.log('Failed with', rejection.status, 'status');
                if (rejection.status == 403) {
                    $location.url('/dashboard');
                }

                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    };
    module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
    });
```