# Creation of Local Storage in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a user based login page in angularjs. When username and password are entered, an url is built and that url returns an id(say a number). Based on this id the tab.html page is returned(This page is different for different customers). Now the problem iam facing is, when logout is clicked, login page is displayed but still return back option is available in browser, which means even if user logs out he can click on back arrow to go to the previous confidential page.

Here is the code of how the states are called:

```
var wc = angular.module('wc', ['ui.router', 'am.multiselect', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker', 'LocalStorageModule']);

wc.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
$stateProvider
         .state('login', {
             url: '/login',
             templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
             controller: 'LoginCtrl'
         })

     .state('logout', {
         cache: false,
         url: '/logout',
         templateUrl: 'views/logout.html',
         controller: 'LogoutCtrl'
     })


  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/tab.html'
  });
```

Below is the code for logout and login controllers:

```
wc.controller('LogoutCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
$location.path('/tab');
});
wc.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.submit = function () {
    $http.get("urlUserName=" + $scope.person.firstName + "&Password=" + $scope.person.pswd)//Sample Url//
     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         debugger
         $scope.tableData = data;
         console.log(data)
         if (data == 'Exception') {
             window.alert('You have entered wrong username or password');

         }
         else $state.go('tab', { id: data.Table[0].UserId });
     })
}});
```

Below is the code for form in login page:

```
   <form ng-submit=submit()>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="text" id="Username" ng-model="person.firstName" required="required" />
                <label for="Username">Username</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="password" id="Password" ng-model="person.pswd" required="required" />
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="submit">               
                <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
            </div>
        </form>
```

I understood that i'll have to use localStorage and added it to code as below:

```
<script src="bower_components/js/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule']);
  myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  var lsKeys = localStorageService.keys();//to show all values
  function submit(key, val) {
 return localStorageService.set(key, val);  }
 function removeItem(key) {
  return localStorageService.remove(key); }
  });
```

But the above code didn't work. How can i use local storage here? Will be grateful, if anyone can help me here!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use resolve concept here at that time of routing, you will need to just do is in your $routeProvider :

But before that let me know you about local storage, at that time of login you will need to call your services and store the user detail in local storage like this :

```
$window.localStorage.setItem('user_profile',JSON.stringify(user));// user = your user details of json.
$window.localStorage.setItem('is_login',true);
```

And like this first of all store the user detail in local storage, and then get user from local storage like :

```
var user_tmp = $window.localStorage.getItem('user_profile');
               return JSON.parse(user_tmp);
```

So this was the concept of local storage, now let's talk about the authentication check whenever url will change and access every pages,

```
.state('login', {
             url: '/login',
             templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
             controller: 'LoginCtrl',
             resolve: {login: checkLogin}
         })
```

Then after that, in your js file you can define a checklogin function like this to check for authentication all time when routing will take a place,

```
var checkLogin = function ($q, $location, Auth, $rootScope, Auth) {
    console.log('checkLogin...')
    var deferred = $q.defer(); // Make an AJAX call to check if the user is logged in 
    console.log("call checkLoggedin...");
    /**
     * Check Profile is exits or not Otherwise return login page
     **/
    if (!Auth.checkLogin()) {
        $rootScope.is_login = false;
        deferred.reject();
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    else {
        $rootScope.is_login = true;
        $rootScope.loggedInUserDetails = Auth.getUserLocal();
        deferred.resolve();
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Based upon the returning from check login you can establish the authentication mechenisam.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used angular-local-storage. Why can't you access window.localStorage or chrome.storage object directly instead of angular provided service.

The below code snippet gets and sets values to localStorage.

```
 var appLocalStorage;
    appLocalStorage = appLocalStorage || (function () {
        return {
            setObject: function (objectName, objectValue) {
                if (window && window.localStorage) {
                    window.localStorage.setObject(objectName, objectValue);
                }
                else if (chrome && chrome.storage && chrome.storage.local) {
                    var dataObj = {};
                    dataObj[objectName] = objectValue;
                    chrome.storage.local.set(dataObj, function () {

                    });
                }
            },
            getObject: function (objectName) {
                if (window && window.localStorage) {
                    return window.localStorage.getObject(objectName);
                }
                else if (chrome && chrome.storage && chrome.storage.local) {
                    chrome.storage.local.get(objectName, function (data) {
                        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                            return;
                        }
                        return data;
                    });
                }
            },

        };

    })();
```

To access/write values to localStorage object use below code.

```
appLocalStorage.setObject('appObjects', appObjects);
var appObjects = appLocalStorage.getObject('appObjects');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure though: I see you have submit function in your view, are you passing the correct `key and value` to your `function`.

```
function submit(key, val) {
    return localStorageService.set(key, val);  }

function removeItem(key) {
    return localStorageService.remove(key); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I hope it will help. I will give you steps, how to perform it:

1. Login the user. If login successfull, set the localstorage and redirect to the 'tab' page otherwise display an error.
2. If User logged out then remove the localstorage key and redirect to 'login' page.
3. Use HttpInterceptor which will validate whether user is logged in or not on each page transition. Here, Your back key never go to the 'tab' page until and unless user gets logged in.

For your reference, i will suggest these link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27698084/6124000

http://onehungrymind.com/winning-http-interceptors-angularjs/